# Hibernate query with join: QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join, orm

I want to make a query using join , i tested it but i have this error

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token..

i did:

```
public List <Card>getCard(Client c) {
        ClientDAO cd = new ClientDAO();
        List<Card> ca = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("select ca.column1,e.column2 from card ca join ens e on ca.ide=e.ide where ca.idclient="+ cd.getClient(c).getIdclient()).list();//this is a method to get the current client
        return ca;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used an SQL syntax to write a HQL query. In case the `Card` entity has an `ens` association, you would write a query like this:

```
List<Card> ca = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery(
        "select ca " +
                "from Card ca " +
                "join fetch ca.ens " +
                "where ca.idclient = :idclient")
        .setParameter("idclient", cd.getClient(c).getIdclient())
        .list();
    return ca;
}
```

If you want an SQL query, since you have a projection, you would write a native query instead:

```
List<Object[]> ca = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery(
        "select ca.column1, e.column2 " +
        "from card ca " +
        "join ens e on ca.ide=e.ide " +
        "where ca.idclient = :idclient")
    .setParameter("idclient", cd.getClient(c).getIdclient())
.list();
```

In this case you get a `List` of `Object[]`. Each `Object[]` is associated to a selected row, and each array element is a column value.

Comment: Do you know the cause of this error:
**Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1**

Comment: How to write this using **HQL** please

Comment: I've already given you an HQL query. For the missing dialect you'll find another SO answer for sure.